# Can Material UI Style a card to darken and display text on hover within react JS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

**Question:** I have a series of cards in material UI:

```
<Grid item xs={3}>
  <Card>
    img src="assets/rustyShackelford.jpg" alt="notDale"
  </Card>
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={3}>
  <Card>
    img src="assets/rustyShackelford.jpg" alt="notDale"
  </Card>
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={3}>
  <Card>
    img src="assets/rustyShackelford.jpg" alt="notDale"
  </Card>
</Grid>
```

I want to make it so that when you hover over the card, it fades to a darker grey and the image has text appear on it like so:

**Original:**
[image]

**Desired:**

[image]

**Here's what I've tried:**

1. Adding sx inline to the card directly:

   <Card sx={{ width: '360px', height: '250px' }}>
2. Creating default onMouseOver onMouseOutFunctions:

   ```
    function handleMouseOver() {
        setIsHovered( true );
        //do styling
    }

    function handleMouseOut() {
        setIsHovered( false );
        //remove styling
    }
      ...

     <Card 
      onMouseOver={ handleMouseOver }
      onMouseOut={ handleMouseOut }
      >
   ```
3. Found a bunch of examples of people doing this manually in HTML (it has to be in JSX)
4. Looked at the MUI transition documentation

I feel like there should be an out of the box way to do this. Otherwise I'm going to press on with option 2.

Comment: You can do it in either the theme (global), via `styled` components (reusable one-off), or within the `sx` prop (one-off) depending on the use-case. Sounds like in your case you'd want to use `sx` or `styled`. (Not quite sure what you mean by "has to be in JSX" ... does that mean not in external CSS files or does that mean controlled by JS and/or not `:hover`?)